# How to change a set value in a list in python

Tags: python, list

If i want to replace a set value in a list with another, how can I do this without adding more values.

```
file = ['10230', '12300', '12003']
for ballot in file:
    if ballot[1] == "2" or ballot[1] == "3":
        ballot[1] = "0"

#everything is stored as a string as in the real program its reading from a file
```

error occuring:

```
ballot[1] = "0"

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: `ballot isn't a list...

Comment: try this : for ballot in range(len(file)):

Comment: Strings are immutable in Python.

Comment: @Mohammad that fails. You could test that yourself

Comment: @roganjosh yes instead of of there should be len(file)

Comment: `[10230,12300,12003]` these are numerical values. `ballot[1]` is NOT defined

Comment: word of caution, modifying a list you are looping over can cause you a headache down the road

Comment: @accdias I think that might be the problem... is there a way I can change all values to become an integer (i'm reading from a file which takes them as a string)

Comment: @Mohammad and an `enumerate`. Your suggestion is just broken

Comment: @aws_apprentice Changing the *structure* of the list causes problems. Replacing one item with another does not.

Answer (score 1):

A string is immutable; you have to replace the entire string.

```
file = ["10230", "12300", "12003"]
for i, ballot in enumerate(file):
    if ballot[1] in {"2", "3"}:
        file[i] = ballot[0] + "0" + ballot[2:]
```

Comment: So, I'll delete my answer in a minute. Haha.

Comment: @makis [accdias's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59364479/1126841) is fine as well. (Better, actually, since the f-string is more efficient than the simple string construction I used here.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on [Python 3.6+](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), you can do this:

```py
files = ['10230', '12300', '12003']
files = [f'{x[0]}0{x[2:]}' if x[1] in '23' else x for x in files]
```

And here is a proof of concept:

```py
Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 17 2019, 12:16:48) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> files = ['10230', '12300', '12003']
>>> files = [f'{x[0]}0{x[2:]}' if x[1] in '23' else x for x in files]
>>> files
['10230', '10300', '10003']
>>>
```